# Writing a function to convert a circle to a polygon using Leaflet.js

Tags: openlayers, leaflet

Here is an example of how to write a function that does this in ol2 http://jsfiddle.net/4S5Ke/166/ Here's some of the code:

```
function createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, sides, rotation, projection) {

if (projection.getCode() !== "EPSG:4326") {
    origin.transform(projection, new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
}
var latlon = new OpenLayers.LonLat(origin.x, origin.y);

var angle;
var new_lonlat, geom_point;
var points = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
    angle = (i * 360 / sides) + rotation;
    new_lonlat = OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty(latlon, angle, radius);
    new_lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), projection);
    geom_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(new_lonlat.lon, new_lonlat.lat);
    points.push(geom_point);
}
var ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
return new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([ring]);
```

}

What are the leaflet equivalents to functions like OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty and OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing? Knowing that, I think I could rewrite the function to work using leaflet. Help??

Comment: At the end of the day, Vincenty formula is well know, even if the math is a bit hairy, and OpenLayers is open source. Just rewrite the function that appears here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js

Comment: Thanks John B. May have to do actually do as you suggest but I was hoping I didn't have to. ;) By the way, I think I may have figured out a leaflet equivalent to OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(). I think it's L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea()?? Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Looks like you have your answer below. There is a plugin for everything in leaflet it seems.

Answer (score 13):

Well.. What I wound up doing was rewriting a couple of OpenLayers 2 functions so that they'll work using Leaflet. One function creates a regular polygon around a radius. It looks like this:

```
function createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, sides, rotation, projection) {
  var latlon = origin; //leaflet equivalent
  var angle;
  var new_lonlat, geom_point;
  var points = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
      angle = (i * 360 / sides) + rotation;
      new_lonlat = destinationVincenty(latlon, angle, radius); 
      geom_point = L.latLng(new_lonlat.lng, new_lonlat.lat); 

      points.push(geom_point); 
    }   

  return points; 
}
```

Now for some trig. First, we set some constants:

```
L.Util.VincentyConstants = {
    a: 6378137,
    b: 6356752.3142,
    f: 1/298.257223563  
};
```

Then we rewrite the OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty function http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Util-js.html#Util.destinationVincenty to work with Leaflet.

Parameters:
lonlat  - (any object with both .lat, .lng properties) The start point.
brng    - {Float} The bearing (degrees).
dist    - {Float} The ground distance (meters).

Returns:
{L.latLng} The destination point.

Lots of trig functions. Don't get scared. We only have to change a couple of lines (Thanks for the idea John B. The function looks like this for leaflet.

```
function destinationVincenty(lonlat, brng, dist) { //rewritten to work with leaflet

    var u = L.Util;
    var ct = u.VincentyConstants;
    var a = ct.a, b = ct.b, f = ct.f;
    var lon1 = lonlat.lng;
    var lat1 = lonlat.lat;
    var s = dist;
    var pi = Math.PI;
    var alpha1 = brng * pi/180 ; //converts brng degrees to radius
    var sinAlpha1 = Math.sin(alpha1);
    var cosAlpha1 = Math.cos(alpha1);
    var tanU1 = (1-f) * Math.tan( lat1 * pi/180 /* converts lat1 degrees to radius */ ); 
    var cosU1 = 1 / Math.sqrt((1 + tanU1*tanU1)), sinU1 = tanU1*cosU1;
    var sigma1 = Math.atan2(tanU1, cosAlpha1);
    var sinAlpha = cosU1 * sinAlpha1;
    var cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha*sinAlpha;
    var uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a*a - b*b) / (b*b);
    var A = 1 + uSq/16384*(4096+uSq*(-768+uSq*(320-175*uSq)));
    var B = uSq/1024 * (256+uSq*(-128+uSq*(74-47*uSq)));
    var sigma = s / (b*A), sigmaP = 2*Math.PI;
    while (Math.abs(sigma-sigmaP) > 1e-12) {
        var cos2SigmaM = Math.cos(2*sigma1 + sigma);
        var sinSigma = Math.sin(sigma);
        var cosSigma = Math.cos(sigma);
        var deltaSigma = B*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+B/4*(cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)-
            B/6*cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*sinSigma*sinSigma)*(-3+4*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));
        sigmaP = sigma;
        sigma = s / (b*A) + deltaSigma;
    }
    var tmp = sinU1*sinSigma - cosU1*cosSigma*cosAlpha1;
    var lat2 = Math.atan2(sinU1*cosSigma + cosU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1,
        (1-f)*Math.sqrt(sinAlpha*sinAlpha + tmp*tmp));
    var lambda = Math.atan2(sinSigma*sinAlpha1, cosU1*cosSigma - sinU1*sinSigma*cosAlpha1);
    var C = f/16*cosSqAlpha*(4+f*(4-3*cosSqAlpha));
    var lam = lambda - (1-C) * f * sinAlpha *
        (sigma + C*sinSigma*(cos2SigmaM+C*cosSigma*(-1+2*cos2SigmaM*cos2SigmaM)));  
    var revAz = Math.atan2(sinAlpha, -tmp);  // final bearing
    var lamFunc = lon1 + (lam * 180/pi); //converts lam radius to degrees
    var lat2a = lat2 * 180/pi; //converts lat2a radius to degrees

    return L.latLng(lamFunc, lat2a);

}
```

Since I was using Leaflet.Draw to create the circle, I called it like this:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
        if (type === 'circle') {

            var origin = layer.getLatLng(); //center of drawn circle
            var radius = layer.getRadius(); //radius of drawn circle
            var projection = L.CRS.EPSG4326;
            var polys = createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, 60, 0, projection); //these are the points that make up the circle
            var polygon = []; // store the geometry
            for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
                var geometry = [polys[i].lat, polys[i].lng]; 
                polygon.push(geometry);
            }

            var polyCircle = L.polygon(polygon).addTo(map); //convert geometry to a leaflet polygon and add it to the map

        } else {....}
```

That's it! Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice one, always satisfying to do it yourself. I just checked and OpenLayers has a BDS license so no worries about using the Vincenty formula -- the math is publicly available anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin: there's [Leaflet.Geodesic](https://github.com/Fragger/Leaflet.Geodesic) and [leaflet-geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) to choose from, each provide geodesic circles.